# asymmetry in matplotlib histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

After reading through the matplotlib documentation about histograms I did expect, that range ignores lower and upper outliers.

"range : tuple, optional, default: None
    The lower and upper range of the bins. Lower and upper outliers
    are ignored. If not provided, `range` is (x.min(), x.max()). Range
    has no effect if `bins` is a sequence."

Have a look at the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numbers1 = np.arange(1.,101.)
numbers2 = np.arange(0.5,100.5)
numbers3 = np.arange(0,100)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.hist(numbers1, bins = 25, range = (25,75), normed=True)
plt.title('numbers1')
plt.ylim((0,0.035))
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.hist(numbers2, bins = 25, range = (25,75), normed=True)
plt.title('numbers2')
plt.ylim((0,0.035))
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.hist(numbers3, bins = 25, range = (25,75), normed=True)
plt.title('numbers3')
plt.ylim((0,0.035))
```

Unfortunately I can not post the image of the outcome... (not enough reputations), BUT: the histogram of numbers1 and numbers3 both have a value that is higher than the one I expected for the last bin.

Why does this happen, and should it really be that way? I expected all of them to look like the middle one. :-(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All numbers in the range 25-75 are used for the histogram. For arrays `numbers1` and `numbers3`, that are exactly 51 numbers since both 25 and 75 are included. You force these numbers in 25 bins, which means that there will be 24 bins of height `2/51` and one of height `3/51`. Matplotlib chooses to put 73, 74 and 75 all in the last bin and make that the largest.

For `numbers2`, there are only 50 numbers in the range, being 25.5 to 74.5. Therefore, every bin's height is `2/50`.

You can see that, for `numbers1` and `numbers3`, when you make the range `(25, 74.99999)` or `(25.0000001, 75)` the higher bins disappear, since either 25 or 75 is excluded and there are 50 numbers in the range.

---

You can get the limits of the bins, since `plt.hist` returns the values, the bins and the patches. So if you use

```
(n, bins, p) = plt.hist(numbers1, bins = 25, range = (25,75), normed=True)
```

`bins` contains an array of the 26 limits of the bins. So this is all the starting points of the bins plus the end of the last bin. Using this you can exactly deduce in which bin each value has gone.

Comment: Thank you so much! Matplotlib will always by default choose to put all in the last bin or might there be occasions, where stuff finishes else where as well?

Comment: It depends on how the bins are defined. If you'd make the range `(25, 75.01)`, every bin would be a little bit bigger so the first bin would fit 25, 26 and 27. With the range from 25 to 75 and having exactly the numbers 25 to 75 you have an edge case and matplotlib apparently uses the last bin.